# Позволить для текстового поля результаты только из выпадающего списка

Tags: javascript, select2

В выпадающем списке при вводе предлагаются города. Как сделать средствами плагина так, чтобы позволялись только значения из выпадающего списка? Т.е., чтобы человек не мог оставить поле просто введя название города.

Comment: делай поиск введенного по наличию в выпадающем списке

Comment: @sair дело в том что при выборе из списка заполняются hidden поля кодов города